# Validating Dynamically Added Form Inputs - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm building a multipage form.  On a few of the form's pages, I have questions that allow the user to add inputs dynamically if they need to add a job, or an award, etcetera. Here's what I'd like to do/what I have done so far.

***What I Want to Do:***

1. As the user adds fields dynamically, I want to validate those fields to make sure they have been filled in, and they are not just trying to move to the next page of the form with empty inputs.
2. After all the fields are successfully validated, a "Next" button at the bottom of the page, which up until this point was disabled, will become reenabled.

***What I know How To Do***

With some help, I've been able to workout a validation pattern for the inputs that are not dynamically added (such as First Name, Last Name) and I can extend this same logic to the first set of inputs that are not added dynamically. I have also worked out how to re-enable the "Next" button once all fields are good.

***What I do Not Know How To Do***

How do I write a function that extends the logic of the simple validation test to also check for dynamically added iterations.

http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/gwKAQX

```js
var i = 0;
function addJob()
{
   
   //if(i <= 1)
   //{
        i++;
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="three-lines" placeholder="School Board" name="schoolBoard_'+i+'"> <input type="text" class="three-lines" placeholder="Position" name="position_'+i+'"> <input type="date" class="three-lines" name="years_'+i+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeJob(this)">';
    
    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").appendChild(div);
  //}
}

function removeJob(div)
{
    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    i--;
};



function checkPage2()
{
    
    var schoolBoard_1 = document.getElementById("schoolBoard_1").value;
    
    if(!schoolBoard_1.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
    {
        console.log("something is wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Working");
    }
};
```

```html
 <div id="page2-content">
                <div class="input-group" id="previousTeachingExperience">
                    <p class="subtitleDirection">Please list in chronological order, beginning with your most recent, any and all full-time or part-time teaching positions you have held.</p>
                    <div class="clearFix"></div>
                    <label id="teachingExpierience">Teaching Experience *</label>
                    <div id="employmentHistory">
                        <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_1" id="schoolBoard_1" placeholder="School Board" onblur="this.placeholder='School Board'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />
                        <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_1" placeholder="Position" onblur="this.placeholder='Position'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />
                        <input type="date" class="three-lines" name="years_1" />
                        <input type="button" name="myButton" onclick="addJob()" value="+" />
                    </div>     
                </div><!--end of previousTeachingExperience Div -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every element that you make with `document.createElement(...)`, you can bind to the `onchange` event of the input element, and then perform your validation.

Here's an [updated version of your CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwKLrL?editors=1111).

For example:

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var inputElement = document.createElement("input");

inputElement.type = "text";
inputElement.onchange = function(e){
    console.log("Do validation!");
};

container.appendChild(inputElement);
```

In this case I'm directly creating the input element so I have access to its `onchange` property, but you can easily also create a wrapping div and append the `inputElement` to that.

**Note:** Depending on the freqency in which you want the validation to fire, you could bind to the `keyup` event instead, which fires every time the user releases a key while typing in the box, IE:

```
inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    console.log("Do validation!");
});
```

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding your example. Can you work with the fiddle I have provided?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner certainly. I'll post an updated version shortly.

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner What browsers are you supporting with this? If its any HTML5 compliant browser, you don't need to do this in the Javascript. HTML5 has a built-in way to validate against regex.

Comment: In as many as possible. Basically, If I can validate what's happening, I'll be able to log it when it comes time to actually "submit" the form.  But I don't understand how to capture the specific iterations past the first layer. If you have a way or even an example based off mine I could learn from, that would be amazing.

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Please check this codepen out. I modified your code slightly so that the School Board is always validated even on multiple inputs: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwKLrL?editors=1111

Comment: This is interesting.  The way you've written the validateSchoolBoard, can I apply it to each field?  That's essentially what I need to do.  I also have another question, when it comes time, eventually, to submit, will the values  on the dynamically added lines be able to post through?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Yes, you can. All you need is a function that takes in the element in question, and then validate that element in the function. To answer your second question, as long as the input has a *unique* name, it will be available on the POST.

Comment: One more question, with your layout, can I make separate functions for each field, puit them within the checkForm() and just run that single function onkeyup?

Comment: One more question, with your layout, can I make separate functions for each field, puit them within the checkForm() and just run that single function onkeyup? I'm just confused about why I need both the checkForm() AND the validateSchoolBoard()

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Sure, you can have one, as long as you can pass a reference to those inputs in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to validate each individual input element, I would recommend trying to validate them all at once. I believe that is what your checkPage2 function is doing.

You can add the onBlur event handler or the onKeyUp event handler you are currently using to all added inputs to run your form wide validation. This has the effect of checking each individual form element if it is valid so you know for sure you can enable the submit button.

Lastly, when removeJob is called, you should also run the form wide validation. It would look something like this:

```
function addJob()
{
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="three-lines" placeholder="School Board" name="schoolBoard_'+i+'" onkeyup="checkPage2()"> <input type="text" class="three-lines" placeholder="Position" name="position_'+i+'" onkeyup="checkPage2()"> <input type="date" class="three-lines" name="years_'+i+'" onkeyup="checkPage2()"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeJob(this)">';

    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").appendChild(div);
}

function removeJob(div)
{
    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    i--;
    checkPage2();
};
```

Comment: Do I need to be calling anything special in the checkFormPage2 function so it knows to look at the appended child?